# Code coverage aggregate result in test class for VF user input page

Tags: visualforce, code-coverage, wrapper-class

I'm having a hard tome covering the wrapper class for an aggregation in a test class. I'm only getting 48%. Can anyone see what I am missing? This Apex supports a VF page, where the user selects the obj, per and sta variables, hits a button that passes these variables to the Apex class for the query and the results are then displayed on another VF page (PDF) that they can easily print. The process works well but the test class is causing me some issues.

Apex Class

```
public class ExpenseReport {       
    Public String obj {get; set;}
    Public String per {get; set;}
    Public String sta {get; set;}
    Public List <Expenses__c> Oplist {get; set;}
    Public List <Expenses__c> Passlist {get; set;}                
    public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }

public pageReference ExpenseReport()
    {
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/Expense_Report');
        pg.setRedirect(false);
        return pg;
    }
    
    Public void getobj() {
        Passlist= new list<Expenses__c> ( [select id, Expense_Status__c, Expense_Incurred_by1__c, Total_Expense_Amount__c, RecordTypeId, Date__c, Description__c, 
                                            GST_Claim__c, HST_Claim__c, QST_Claim__c, Golf_100_Amount__c, Meal_Entertainment_50_Amount__c, Gross_Tip_PST__c, GST__c, 
                                            HST__c, QST__c,Expense_Budget_Owner1__c, Type__c, EOCY__c,Number_of_Attendees__c, Per_Advisor_Share__c, Company_Name__c, 
                                            Expense_Period__c, Name, (select id, Advisor_Name__c from Expense_Contact_Associations__r) from Expenses__c 
                          WHERE CreatedDate = Last_N_Days:330 AND Expense_incurred_by1__c =:obj AND Expense_Period__c = :per 
                          AND (Expense_Status__c = :sta OR (RecordTypeId = :'0121O000001q4sV' AND Expense_Period__c ='Approved') 
                          OR (RecordTypeId = :'0121O000001q4sX'AND Expense_Period__c ='Approved'))
                          order by Type__c, Date__c]);
                          
                                                             
        
        AggregateResult[] results= [select Type__c, SUM(Total_Expense_Amount__c) totexp, SUM(GST_Claim__c) GSTc, SUM(HST_Claim__c) HSTc, 
                                    SUM(QST_Claim__c) QSTc, SUM(Golf_100_Amount__c) Golfamt, SUM(Meal_Entertainment_50_Amount__c)Mealamt, SUM(Gross_Tip_PST__c) Gross, 
                                    SUM(GST__c) GST, SUM(HST__c) HST, SUM(QST__c) QST from Expenses__c 
                          WHERE CreatedDate = Last_N_Days:330 AND Expense_incurred_by1__c =:obj AND Expense_Period__c = :per 
                          AND (Expense_Status__c = :sta OR (RecordTypeId = :'0121O000001q4sV' AND Expense_Period__c ='Approved') 
                          OR (RecordTypeId = :'0121O000001q4sX'AND Expense_Period__c ='Approved'))
                          Group by rollup(Type__c)];
                          
                          Summaries = new List<Summary>();
                            for (AggregateResult ar : results) {
                            Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
                            }             
           }                                 
     public class Summary {
        public Decimal Totalexp { get; set; }
        public Decimal GSTc { get; set; }
        public Decimal HSTc { get; set; }
        public Decimal QSTc { get; set; }
        public Decimal Golfamt { get; set; }
        public Decimal Mealamt { get; set; }
        public Decimal Gross { get; set; }
        public Decimal GST { get; set; }
        public Decimal HST { get; set; }
        public Decimal QST { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }

        
        
        public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
            Totalexp = (Decimal) ar.get('totexp'); 
            GSTc = (Decimal) ar.get('GSTc'); 
            HSTc = (Decimal) ar.get('HSTc'); 
            QSTc = (Decimal) ar.get('QSTc'); 
            Golfamt = (Decimal) ar.get('Golfamt');  
            Mealamt= (Decimal) ar.get('Mealamt'); 
            Gross= (Decimal) ar.get('Gross'); 
            GST = (Decimal) ar.get('GST'); 
            HST = (Decimal) ar.get('HST'); 
            QST = (Decimal) ar.get('QST');                        
            if(String.valueof(ar.get('Type__c'))==NULL){
               Type='Total';
               }else{
               Type = (String) ar.get('Type__c'); 
               }                                
        }
    }                            
                                            
     
public void Search() {
    string objquery='select id, Expense_Status__c, Expense_Incurred_by1__c, Total_Expense_Amount__c, RecordTypeId, Date__c, Description__c, GST_Claim__c, HST_Claim__c, QST_Claim__c, Golf_100_Amount__c, Meal_Entertainment_50_Amount__c, Gross_Tip_PST__c, GST__c, HST__c, QST__c, Expense_Budget_Owner1__c, Type__c, Number_of_Attendees__c, Per_Advisor_Share__c, Company_Name__c, Expense_Period__c, Name From Expenses__c where Expense_incurred_by1__c like \'%'+obj+'%\' AND Expense_period__c like\'%'+per+'%\' AND EOCY__c like \'%'+2020+'%\' AND Expense_Status__c like \'%'+sta+'%\' order by Type__c';
    Oplist = Database.query(objquery);
    }

    }
```

Test Class

```
public class TestExpenseReport {
  
  static testMethod void testExpenseReport() {
  
    String sta = 'Approved';
    String obj = 'Angela Gates';
    String per = 'Feb 15';
    


        Expenses__c e = new Expenses__c(Expense_Status__c =sta,
                                        RecordTypeId ='0121O000001q4sV',
                                        Expense_Incurred_by1__c =obj,
                                        Expense_Period__c =per, 
                                        Description__c ='TestDescrp',
                                        Company_Name__c='TestCompany',
                                        Date__c=System.today(),
                                        GST__c=50,
                                        HST__c=30,
                                        QST__c=20,
                                        PST__c=10,
                                        Type__c= NULL, 
                                        Tip_Amount__c=5,
                                        Gross_Amount__c=500,
                                        Number_of_Attendees__c=5);
                                    
           
     
        Expenses__c e2 = new Expenses__c(Expense_Status__c =sta,
                                        RecordTypeId ='0121O000001q4sV',
                                        Expense_Incurred_by1__c =obj,
                                        Expense_Period__c =per, 
                                        Description__c ='TestDescrp',
                                        Company_Name__c='TestCompany',
                                        Date__c=System.today(),
                                        GST__c=50,
                                        HST__c=30,
                                        QST__c=20,
                                        PST__c=10, 
                                        Tip_Amount__c=5,
                                        Gross_Amount__c=500,
                                        Number_of_Attendees__c=5);
                     
                                   
        
        insert new List<Expenses__c>{e,e2};
 
                                   
 ExpenseReport controller = new ExpenseReport();                                      
               
        controller.ExpenseReport();
        controller.getobj();      
        controller.search();        

        
    
        
 
    }
  
}
```

Code Coverage

[image]

Comment: Your `result` attribute is not returning any row when you run your test class. Revisit the apex class and create test data in such a way that it returns data for `result`.

Comment: Duplicate of [Cover aggregate Result Wrapper Class in test class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321075/cover-aggregate-result-wrapper-class-in-test-class)